# how to convert nsdata to MPMediaitem song iOS Sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mpmediaitem

i converted MPMediaItem to NSData and stored that in database, now i have to convert that NSData to MPMediaItem to play that song in mediaplayer.
  Used below code to convert MPMediaItem to NSData:

```
NSURL *url = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: url options:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset
                                                                  presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

exporter.outputFileType = @"public.mpeg-4";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *exportFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:           
                        @"exported.mp4"];

NSURL *exportURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportFile] retain];
exporter.outputURL = exportURL; 

// do the export
// (completion handler block omitted) 
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^{
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [documentsDirectory 
                                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"exported.mp4"]];


 }];
```

can anyone please tell me how to convert NSData to MPMediaItem.

Comment: can anyone please answer this question

Comment: Sorry,but I have used same you code to convert from MPMediaItem to NSData.but it is not working in my side.do you know what will be reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. An `MPMediaItem` represents an item in the iPod library but third-party apps cannot add anything to that library.

You could however write your `NSData` object to a file and then use its URL with either `AVPlayerItem`/`AVPlayer` or `MPMoviePlayerController` (don't be fooled by the name, it can also play audio-only files).

Comment: Thanks for your reply...can you please post some code to play song using AVPlayer with my stored NSData object...that will be very useful for me

Comment: how to get NSData of MPMediaItem?