# Could I play recorded audio file of type .caf using MPMusicPlayerController?

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, mpmusicplayercontroller

I know how to play music file from library using MPMusicPlayerController, but I wonder if there's  a way to play recorded audio file (.caf format) using the MPMusicPlayerController? I am recording and saving file into NSDocuments Directory. I google it around but couldn't find a way to do so? I can do the same using AVAudioPlayer. But want to do with MPMusicPlayerController. Any suggestions  appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a post similar to what you are asking.

[how to convert nsdata to MPMediaitem song iOS Sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276484/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-mpmediaitem-song-ios-sdk)

Unfortunately MPMusicPlayer only plays songs from the iPod library, and third party apps cannot add to the library. I would suggest playing it with the `MPMoviePlayerController` as it can play audio-only files (as the answer on the other question suggests).

For example:

```
NSURL *audioPathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilepath];
MPMoviePlayerController *audio;
audio = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:audioPathURL];
[audio play];
```